# Collapsing Dataframe Rows along several variables

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks something like this, in which I have several rows for each user, and many NAs in the columns.

| user | Effect T1 | Effect T2 | Effect T3 | Benchmark T1 | Benchmark T2 | Benchmark T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 01 | NA | NA | 02 | NA | NA |
| Tom | NA | 07 | NA | NA | 08 | NA |
| Tom | NA | NA | 13 | NA | NA | 14 |
| Larry | 03 | NA | NA | 04 | NA | NA |
| Larry | NA | 09 | NA | NA | 10 | NA |
| Larry | NA | NA | 15 | NA | NA | 16 |
| Dave | 05 | NA | NA | 06 | NA | NA |
| Dave | NA | 11 | NA | NA | 12 | NA |
| Dave | NA | NA | 17 | NA | NA | 18 |

I want to collapse the columns using the name and filling the values from reach row, this this.

| user | Effect T1 | Effect T2 | Effect T3 | Benchmark T1 | Benchmark T2 | Benchmark T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 01 | 07 | 13 | 02 | 08 | 14 |
| Larry | 03 | 09 | 15 | 04 | 10 | 16 |
| Dave | 05 | 11 | 17 | 06 | 12 | 18 |

How might I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for your help. Update: I've added the dput of a subset of the actual data below.

```
structure(list(name = c("Abraham_Ralph", "Abraham_Ralph", "Abraham_Ralph", 
"Ackerman_Gary", "Adams_Alma", "Adams_Alma", "Adams_Alma", "Adams_Alma", 
"Adams_Sandy", "Aderholt_Robert", "Aderholt_Robert", "Aderholt_Robert", 
"Aderholt_Robert", "Aderholt_Robert", "Aguilar_Pete", "Aguilar_Pete", 
"Aguilar_Pete"), state = c("LA", "LA", "LA", "NY", "NC", "NC", 
"NC", "NC", "FL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "CA", "CA", "CA"
), seniority = c(1, 2, 3, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3), legeffect_112 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.202061712741852, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.30758035182953, 3.73544979095459, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), legeffect_113 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.908495426177979, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), legeffect_114 = c(2.07501077651978, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.84164834022522, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.340001106262207, 
NA, NA, 0.10985741019249, NA, NA), legeffect_115 = c(NA, 0.493490308523178, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.587624311447144, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.159877583384514, 
NA, NA, 0.730929613113403, NA), legeffect_116 = c(NA, NA, 0.0397605448961258, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.78378939628601, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0198802724480629, 
NA, NA, 0.0497006773948669), benchmark_112 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.738679468631744, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.82908970117569, 1.39835929870605, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), benchmark_113 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.391001850366592, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.58223271369934, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    benchmark_114 = c(1.40446054935455, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.576326191425323, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.42212760448456, NA, NA, 0.574363172054291, 
    NA, NA), benchmark_115 = c(NA, 1.3291300535202, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0.537361204624176, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.45703768730164, 
    NA, NA, 0.523149251937866, NA), benchmark_116 = c(NA, NA, 
    0.483340591192245, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.31058621406555, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.751261711120605, NA, NA, 1.05683290958405
    )), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Help us play here with a dput() of Tom, Larry and Dave.

Comment: What happens when e.g. Tom has two different values in the column "Effect T1", for example 01 in first row, and 02 in the second row?

Comment: @user51187286016, that shouldn't happen. Each user should only have a single value for each column.

Comment: Okay, but in the example data that you gave, `Abraham_Ralph` has seniority 1,2,3. Which one should be picked, and what is the general rule?

Comment: @user51187286016, sorry. the seniority column shouldn't have been included in the dput data. It's my first time using it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution:

```
# melt data, remove NA, then recast ...
dt <- dcast(melt(data.table(d), "name")[!value %in% NA], name ~ variable)

dcast(melt(data.table(d), "name")[!value %in% c(NA) & !variable %in% c("variable", "seniority", "state")], name ~ variable)
              name     legeffect_112     legeffect_113     legeffect_114     legeffect_115      legeffect_116     benchmark_112     benchmark_113     benchmark_114     benchmark_115     benchmark_116
1:   Abraham_Ralph              <NA>              <NA>  2.07501077651978 0.493490308523178 0.0397605448961258              <NA>              <NA>  1.40446054935455   1.3291300535202 0.483340591192245
2:   Ackerman_Gary 0.202061712741852              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>               <NA> 0.738679468631744              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>
3:      Adams_Alma              <NA>                 0  0.84164834022522 0.587624311447144   1.78378939628601              <NA> 0.391001850366592 0.576326191425323 0.537361204624176  1.31058621406555
4:     Adams_Sandy  1.30758035182953              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>               <NA>  0.82908970117569              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>
5: Aderholt_Robert  3.73544979095459 0.908495426177979 0.340001106262207 0.159877583384514 0.0198802724480629  1.39835929870605  1.58223271369934  1.42212760448456  1.45703768730164 0.751261711120605
6:    Aguilar_Pete              <NA>              <NA>  0.10985741019249 0.730929613113403 0.0497006773948669              <NA>              <NA> 0.574363172054291 0.523149251937866  1.05683290958405
```

#### Data/Setup

```
# Load data.table
# install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# Read example data
d <- structure(list(name = c("Abraham_Ralph", "Abraham_Ralph", "Abraham_Ralph", 
"Ackerman_Gary", "Adams_Alma", "Adams_Alma", "Adams_Alma", "Adams_Alma", 
"Adams_Sandy", "Aderholt_Robert", "Aderholt_Robert", "Aderholt_Robert", 
"Aderholt_Robert", "Aderholt_Robert", "Aguilar_Pete", "Aguilar_Pete", 
"Aguilar_Pete"), state = c("LA", "LA", "LA", "NY", "NC", "NC", 
"NC", "NC", "FL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "CA", "CA", "CA"
), seniority = c(1, 2, 3, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3), legeffect_112 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.202061712741852, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.30758035182953, 3.73544979095459, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), legeffect_113 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.908495426177979, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), legeffect_114 = c(2.07501077651978, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.84164834022522, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.340001106262207, 
NA, NA, 0.10985741019249, NA, NA), legeffect_115 = c(NA, 0.493490308523178, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.587624311447144, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.159877583384514, 
NA, NA, 0.730929613113403, NA), legeffect_116 = c(NA, NA, 0.0397605448961258, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.78378939628601, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0198802724480629, 
NA, NA, 0.0497006773948669), benchmark_112 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.738679468631744, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.82908970117569, 1.39835929870605, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), benchmark_113 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.391001850366592, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.58223271369934, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    benchmark_114 = c(1.40446054935455, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.576326191425323, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.42212760448456, NA, NA, 0.574363172054291, 
    NA, NA), benchmark_115 = c(NA, 1.3291300535202, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0.537361204624176, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.45703768730164, 
    NA, NA, 0.523149251937866, NA), benchmark_116 = c(NA, NA, 
    0.483340591192245, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.31058621406555, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.751261711120605, NA, NA, 1.05683290958405
    )), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Does this work for you using the dput data I provided? I'm trying to use your code, but I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: @lwe, updated with your test data

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using only the `base` functions (no extra packages), but the one-liner may cause eyes to cross, so I'll split it into several functions.

The plan is the following:

1. Split the original `data.frame` by the values in `name` column, using the function `by`;
2. For each partition of the `data.frame`, collapse the columns;
3. A collapsed column returns the max value of the column, or `NA` if all its values are `NA`;
4. The collapsed `data.frame` partitions are stacked together.

So, this is a function that does that:

```
dfr_collapse <- function(dfr, col0)
{
    # Collapse the columns of the data.frame "dfr" grouped by the values of
    # the column "col0"

    # Max/NA function
    namax <- function(x)
    {
        if(all(is.na(x)))
            NA   # !!!
        else
            max(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    }

    # Column collapse function
    byfun <- function(x)
    {
        lapply(x, namax)
    }

    # Stack the partitioning results
    return(do.call(
       what = rbind,
       args = by(dfr, dfr[[col0]], byfun)
    ))
}
```

May not look as slick as a one-liner, but it does the job. It can be tunrned into a one-liner, but you don't want that.

Assuming that `df0` is the `data.frame` from you `dput`, you can test this function with

```
dfr_collapse(df0)
```

*Nota bene:* for the sake of simplicity, I return an `NA` of type `logical` (see the comment `# !!!` above). The correct code should convert that `NA` to the mode of the `x` vector. Also, the function should check the type of its inputs, etc.

Comment: Quite striking, people usually do so little with `return`.